# PostgreSQL-pgadmin format backup (.backup)

Tags: postgresql, format, backup, restore, pgadmin

I create backup and get name base.backup.
Create another copy and get name base.sql.

What's the difference in backup formats .sql - .backup then using pgadmin?

I would be grateful if there is a link to the source.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to say  `*.sql` is the plain text version and `*.backup` is the custom format version. Easiest way to find out is open the file in a text editor, you should be able to read the `*.sql` content and see gibberish in the `*.backup` file. Information on backups in pgAdmin4 is here [Backup](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.7/backup_dialog.html).

Comment: I create 2 backups. One script, i change name backup in command  "pg_dump -Fc -U $dbUser $dbname > $backup_path/$dbname-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").sql" to .backup. And nothing has changed. They are the same size in bytes.

Comment: Per the answer, the file extension does not change the file type produced. The type of backup is determined by the options you provide to `pg_dump`. See here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your files whatever you want.  PgAdmin4 does not force you to use specific extensions for specific formats.  It would be sensible to use *.sql for plain-format and *.backup for custom format, but pgAdmin4 does nothing to enforce (or even effectively encourage) this.

Comment: Find. "The Backup dialog invokes options of the pg_dump client utility; the Restore dialog invokes options of the pg_restore client utility."
Thank you.